# matplotlib heat map some entries missing values

Tags: matplotlib, plot, grid, heatmap

Right now my data looks like this:

```
nn = ["1W", "1F", "1V",,,,,"2W", "2F", "2V",,,,,"260W", 261F', "261V",,,,]
```

Essentially each number has the same number of letters corresponding to it. 19 letters in total. And I have 4798 numbers. Basically, I have 4978*19 points in my list.

I have another list that looks like this:

```
value=[1.15, 0.67, 0.88..........]
```

each value corresponds to the character in my nn list. That means I have 4978*19 values in my value list.

Essentially, I want a 2D grid plot with x axis corresponding to the number and y axis corresponding to the letter. Each cell represents the value. I need different colors to present different values. Maybe one color covers a range of values. like red color represents 1-10, blue represents 10-20??
To get a better sense of what I'm trying to plot. I hand drew a plot to visualize.

[image]

I could split my nn list into x-aixs and y-axis.

```
x_axis = [1,2,3,.......4978]

y_axis = ["W", "V", "F", .....] #19 in total
```

One problem That I may run into is that because I have so many numbers. The plot will look humongous. So maybe I could split one big ass plot into subplots???

Also, some entries in my value list might be missing data, like value[100]=' ', or like value[101]='infinity'. The point is len(value) is still equal to 4978*19. So I also want some color to represent insufficient data.

Answer (score 1):

Given what you've shown of `nn`, it looks like the corresponding values are in order.
Therefore, I think you could convert your list to a 2D NumPy array

```
values = np.array(values).reshape((19, 4978))
```

and then plot them using `plt.imshow(values)`. For example,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# generate some random values
values = np.random.random(19*4978).tolist()

# convert the list to a 2D NumPy array
values = np.array(values).reshape((19, 4978))
h, w = values.shape

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.imshow(values)
plt.colorbar()
plt.yticks(np.arange(h), list('PNIYLKCVFWABCDEFGHI'))
ax.set_aspect(w/h)
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

Note that while the default colormap, viridis, is not as colorful as the example
you drew, it does have some [very interesting
features](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAoljeRJ3lU). Perhaps the most
important is that the "intensity" of the colors correspond well to a
monotonically increasing scale. Thus you can intuitively "read off" the value
represented by the colors in the plot. The same could not be said of a plot using
the colorful `jet` colormap, or a colormap like the one you proposed where 1--10 is
colored red and 10--20 is colored blue, etc. The reader would be forced to
constantly refer to the colorbar or a legend to check the correspondences between
colors and values.

Comment: Just one more question, what if some data is missing? Like values[0][0] is missing? I tried to plot with values[0][0]=' '. But it just screamed at me saying that couldn't convert string to float.Like I need some color to represent "insufficient data"

Comment: Can I say something like, if values[0][0]==' ', color = 'grey'??

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out. If an entry is missing data, i could just set it to np.nan. It will show up as white on the plot, indicating missing data.

Answer (score 1):

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

n = 12 
data = np.random.randint(0,5, (n,n))
```

Let's consider that where the element value is zero the data is missing (or just `None` value in its place)

```
# Creating a mask which will mask your missing data
Mask = np.zeros(np.shape(data))
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if(data[i][j] == 0):
            Mask[i][j] = True
        else:
            Mask[i][j] = False
            
sns.heatmap(data, mask=Mask, square=True, linewidths=0.01, linecolor='k', cmap='hsv');
```

[image]